# Can't fetch Volunteer Experiences with LinkedIn API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn API via the `linkedin gem` and can't seem to use the correct key in order to get the volunteer experiences of a certain user. I have tried `volunteer-experience`, `volunteer-experiences` and `volunteer-experience-fields`. I couldn't find the correct answer yet.

The error I'm getting is

```
(400): Unknown field {volunteer-experiences} in resource {Person}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some googling also.

This may be what you want:
:(volunteer:(volunteer-experiences,causes,supported-organizations))

http://electric-meadow-1119.herokuapp.com/linkedin

https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

Answer (score 0):

```
volunteer:(volunteer-experiences:(id,role,organization:(name),cause:(name)))
```

seems to work.